# Page shifts up when overflow:hidden css property is set to <html> tag only in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, jquery-dialog

My webpage height is quite long, i have a requirement like when i have a modal dialog in the page, page scroll bar has to be disabled. Since the modal dialog has a scroll bar in it once the modal dialog scroll bar comes to an end, page scroll bar will be activated. To fix this i have added this code to JQuery modal dialog method.

```
   open: function () {
        $("html").css("overflow", "hidden");
        return false;
    },
    close: function () {
        $("html").css("overflow", "visible");
        return false;
    }
```

Now i'm in the bottom of the page on opening the modal dialog the page shifted to top only in Firefox browser, its because of overflow:hidden property added to the  tag, due to this i can't see the modal dialog opened, which is opened in the bottom of the page.

But this code works fine(Page will not shift up) as expected in all other browsers expect Firefox.

Could anyone please suggest me to fix any other way to disable the page scroll bar or how to stop page to shift up only in Firefox.

Thanks
Gopi

Comment: Why do you set it on the html element??? Can't you just set it to the `<body>` tag?

Comment: Yes. Set it to the body element, or better yet, a wrapper div element.

Comment: @PeeHaa Jeffrey - $("body").css("overflow-y", "hidden"); will not work in any browser. you can give a try.

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally attach the css property to your  element rather than the  one, as there is a chance that the property is being inherited. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing the page, but this *could* be caused by the reflow after the `overflow` set being interrupted.  If you add a reflow flush (e.g. `document.body.offsetWidth`) right after the `css()` calls, does that help?